# android - list items open context menus

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listadapter

I'm new to Android. I have a list of items and trying to associate single **context menus** to each list item. I have set **setListAdapter** and **onListItemClick** but when I click on any list item I always get the same context menu.

Ideally, list item A should trigger menu A when cliccked and list item B should get menu B. Can't figure out how to do it. Could anybody help me find an example code I could use to learn how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any example code that shows the technique -- my best example is something I did for a consulting client.

However, let me point you to [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) that uses context menus and use it as a basis for this explanation.

You need to return the customized menu in `onCreateContextMenu()`. If you always return the same menu here, you will always see the same menu. To determine which menu to display, you will need to know which list item was long-tapped. In the case of a context menu for a `ListView`, you can cast the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` supplied to `onCreateContextMenu()` to be an `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`. That object can tell you the position and `_ID` of the item in the list that was long-tapped, so you can choose the proper menu.

In the sample code linked to above, I do that cast in `onContextItemSelected()`, so I can know which item the user is deleting. However, the same cast works in `onCreateContextMenu()`.

Answer (score 1):

The Android team recently released a number of new samples.  I believe what you're trying to do has an excellent example [here](http://d.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List6.html).

Comment: That sample, while good, does not show a context menu, per the posted question.

Comment: Can it be adapted to create the context menu instead of LinearLayout?  I could be wrong, or maybe I chose the wrong sample. I was looking through these last night and there seemed to be way more than are listed on the site.

Comment: I think I meant to link to this one: http://d.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List7.html :) When you select an item, you can build a dialog.